# Accessing data using API by Retrofit

Tags: android, json, api, authentication, retrofit2

[image]

I am accessing the login from API but I don't how to get response in other activity of the user using JSON, as I am new to retrofit. I have set my all the parameters in my classes. The details which should be fetched are as follows. I have added my API as follows.

MainActivity:

```
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                User user=new User(
                        emailid.getText().toString(),
                        password.getText().toString()

                );
                sendNetworkRequest(user);

            }
        });


        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.bgVideoView);
        CreateAccount=(Button) findViewById(R.id.newAccountButton);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video);

        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);


        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0);
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
                mVideoView.start();


            }
        });

       CreateAccount.setOnClickListener(this);

        frgtpassword=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.forgotpassword);
        frgtpassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),ForgetPasswordScreen.class);
startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendNetworkRequest(User user){
        Retrofit.Builder builder= new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.payhans.com/web/sign-in/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit=builder.build();

        UserClient client=retrofit.create(UserClient.class);
        Call<User> call=client.loginUser(user);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yeah!+User-ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "sometihing went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }}
```

UserClient:

```
public interface UserClient {
    @POST("user")
    Call<User>loginUser(@Body User user);
}
```

User

```
public class User {
    private String user_id;
    private String pwd;

    public User(String user_id, String pwd) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

}
```

Comment: what response u r getting

Comment: You should read more docs and see tutorial. This is not a site where you ask anything before trying. You can refer [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit). Try first and ask only if you are stuck.

Comment: you don't need to put @POST("user") instead use @POST()

Comment: i am getting nothing @darwin

Comment: have u tried replacing @POST("user") with @POST() and your response object [Call<User>] is not as found in the document,it contains different values\

Comment: also please try the rest api in any rest client like post man or advanced rest client, so u can make sure that it works fine

Comment: I have tested ur rest api in rest client it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set only the base URL `.baseUrl("https://api.payhans.com/web/")` not the complete URL, then when you annotate the call in the UserClient interface pass the URL `sign-in/` in the POST annotation

```
public interface UserClient {
    @POST("sign-in/")
    Call<User>loginUser(@Body User user);
}
```

Also double check if you are passing data in correct way because you are sending the `User` as `@Body` but in the screenshot of the API it seems that you have to pass `user_id` and `pwd` like URL params.